# Is there a way to get the text from a checked radiobutton from a radiogroup?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a static radiogroup in my XML layout, but I have created all of the radiobuttons dynamically as an effect of user input.  Since none of these have ID's, is there a way I can call a method on a whole radiogroup to just return the text (or label) of the checked radio button?  All the labels are URL's so if I can get the URL of the checked radio button then I can pass it to a method i created to open the web browser.

I can use ID's but then I would have to create a bunch of extra text for the radio button labels anyways, then a bunch of if statements with the labels written a second time.. [ if this ID is selected go to this URL, if this ID is open go to this URL...] Where as I just want to take the RadioButton's label and just put it right into the browser method.

I found this post: [Android: How to get text of dynamically created radio button selected by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070377/android-how-to-get-text-of-dynamically-created-radio-button-selected-by-the-user)

but it wasn't answered correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to looks fine. In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IDs are no good for you, maybe you should use the tag property that all Views have, i.e. call `radioButton.setTag(url)` when you create the button. Then call `View.getTag()` in your onClickListener and cast to a `String` to get your URL back.